# What's the difference between these two SQL statements?

Tags: sql

Here are two SQL statements below which I think are equal, but when I run the scripts the second one is much slower, can anyone tell me why?

First one:

```
select 
    a.name, if(b.score1 = 0, b.score2, b.score1) 
from 
    a, b
where 
    a.id = b.id 
    and if(b.score1 = 0, b.score2, b.score1) > 0
```

Second one:

```
select 
    a.name, temp.score 
from 
    a, b,
    (select if(b.score1 = 0, b.score2, b.score1) as score from b) as temp
where 
    a.id = b.id 
    and temp.score > 0
```

The above is a simple example,if my query is:

```
select a.name,
if(b.usedname1='',if(b.usedname2='',b.usedname3,b.usedname2),b.usedname1)
from a,b 
where a.id=b.id and
if(b.usedName1='',if(b.useNname2='',b.usedname3,b.usedname2),b.usedname1)<>'tom';
```

I got 5 more used names in my table, is there any way to simplify this kind of statement?

Comment: The queries have nothing to do with each other.  Why would you think they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to write the query is to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

I would write this as:

```
select a.name, (case when b.score1 = 0 then b.score2 else b.score1 end)
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id 
where (b.score1 = 0 and b.score2 > 0) or b.score1 > 0;
```

I suspect that you might really want `greatest()` rather than a conditional expression, but that is just speculation.

The second statement has an additional `join`.  I have no idea why you think a query with three table references and two joins would be equivalent to a query with two table references and one join.

Answer (score 0):

If  you'd written the same query, I'd say quite possibly nothing.  Use the query plan generated by whatever DB engine you are using.

However as you have introduced `temp` and still joined to `b` they are not the same.

This is probably the same:

```
select a.name,temp.score from a,temp,
(select if(b.score1=0,b.score2,b.score1) as score from b) as temp
where a.id=temp.id and temp.score>0
```